# Default text in description field of new issue in YouTrack

Tags: templates, issue-tracking, youtrack, youtrack-api

Can a template with default text be created when opening new issues in the **online** YouTrack ?

The **standalone** has this:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Workflow-Default-Description.html?_ga=2.158053754.1913801868.1580634848-1795114126.1570707315&_gac=1.259581432.1580634885.CjwKCAiAg9rxBRADEiwAxKDTui5xiFvmG6K8erIvAz1EPmGcg9N8-cQpoGCt1Qqg5wHM0uaXbrOeLBoCgeUQAvD_BwE#description-template

Answer (score 0):

In case you mean YouTrack InCloud, then yes, it's possible, the standalone and the in cloud versions functionality is almost identical, including the aspect you mention (i.e. workflows).